# Elastic Search got 404 when requesting `entries`

Tags: docker, ubuntu, elasticsearch

I've installed Elastic Search on my Ubuntu Docker container and installed it successfully, but when I try to run this:

```sh
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/entries?pretty"
```

I got 404 error:

```json
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
        "reason" : "no such index [entries]",
        "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
        "resource.id" : "entries",
        "index_uuid" : "_na_",
        "index" : "entries"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
    "reason" : "no such index [entries]",
    "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
    "resource.id" : "entries",
    "index_uuid" : "_na_",
    "index" : "entries"
  },
  "status" : 404
}
```

I've also restarted `elasticsearch` service successfully, but it still doesn't work.

Feedbin need Elastic Search to run and it tried to request `"http://localhost:9200/entries"` but failed. I don't know what's wrong with my configuration...

Answer (score 1):

`curl -X GET "localhost:9200/entries?v&pretty"` will list the mappings for the index named `entries`. Do you have that index in your cluster?

First check if your cluster is `up and running` using `curl -X GET "localhost:9200?pretty"`. If this returns a response with a non-null `cluster_uuid`, it means your ES Cluster is up and running.

Next, check for the health of your ES cluster using `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty"`. Does it show either `green` or `yellow` in `status` field?

Next, list all the indices using `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/indices?pretty"`. This will show you if `entries` index exists or not.

Once you have that index, you can use `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/entries/_search?pretty"` to search documents. It will return top 10 documents.

Comment: I've tried `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/indices?pretty"`, but it shows nothing. So does it mean I need to create an entry, how to?

Comment: Try using `v` as well. If `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty"` shows you nothing except the column headings, then it means your ES set-up is correct but no indices are present in ES cluster. I don't think you need to create it since I reckon this is something `Feedbin` will create for you. I could be wrong since never used `Feedbin` before. Make sure that the elasticsearch version you installed matches the one in `docker-compose.yml` and then you need to specify `ELASTICSEARCH_URL`.

Answer (score 0):

**Listing `curl` commands you could leverage to validate the Elastic Search installation, cluster health, index list & index info.**

1. To check if ElasticSearch is installed successfully : `curl -XGET localhost:9200/`
2. To get a list of indices and information about each index :  `curl http://localhost:9200/_status`
3. To get a list of all indices in your cluster : `curl http://localhost:9200/_aliases?pretty=true`
4. To check Elasticsearch cluster health : `curl http://localhost:9200/_cat/health`

Comment: I got an error when trying curl `http://localhost:9200/_status`, the reason it showed is `Invalid index name [_status], must not start with '_'.`, `status`: `400`, `type`: `invalid_index_name_exception`.

Comment: @Mr.Will Did you figure it out?